# Absolute layout is deprecated

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making Hidden Treasure game and facing lot of problem in making UI for the main game play ..Since absolute layout is deprecated, I am trying to work with relative layout but not getting the same.

Left most side of Screen will have list of objects,timer ...and right will have the gamescreen as it is done in basic Hidden Treasure games ...

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

we can use simple [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and set positions of the child views using 
LayoutParams.leftMargin and LayoutParams.topMargin